# Add Custom Perspective sub menu in Eclipse Open Perspective menu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, usability

One way to open a custom perspective in Eclipse is the following:
[Menu] Window -> Perspective -> Open Perspective -> Others.

Then a dialog opens with a list of perspectives available, where the user can pick the required item.

Is there a way to make the custom perspective menu appear above the "Others" submenu.
This can reduce a few clicks for the users and find the required perspective easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perspectives listed above 'Other' are known as 'perspective shortcuts'.

In the Eclipse UI you can add these using 'Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective'. Choose the 'Shortcuts' tab and select the 'Open Perspective' submenu. You can then select the items to show as 'shortcuts'.

In an Eclipse plugin you can use the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point to specify an `perspectiveShortcut`.

In an `IPerspectiveFactory` you can use the `IPageLayout.addPerspectiveShortcut` method to define a shortcut.